# Check this.balance of another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, balances

Is there a way to check the balance of another contract from a contract without the use of a public variable? (ie. this.balance)

Comment: From where? web3js? From an other contract? Give mo details please.

Comment: Edited the question. (from another contract)

Comment: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related   address.balance isn't that enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the balance of any account in Solidity:

```
address(0x123abc...).balance
```

See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related.